# console.writeline with a click

Tags: c#

Could somebody tell me how I can make a text that the player can click so a Console.WriteLine will be executed?

I'm using Console application in C#.

Comment: You can't really click anything in a console app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't capture mouse events in a console application (without low-level windows API hooks), so you can't do this.

My suggestion is to make it a WinForms or WPF application, and include a textbox which is your console window.

Maybe take a look at [ShellControl](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/shellcontrol.aspx).